# Pass a string as a parameter to a function onclick event jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I want to ask for help because I have a problem creating buttons using a for and put in the onclick the name of a function with a parameter, but this parameter is a string, I get an array and end of the cycle all buttons have the name of the last element of the array rather than each position of the array .. Thanks in advance for your help ..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 function enviar(periodo){
 alert(periodo);
 }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 $formatos=
  array(array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2019'),
      array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2018'),
      array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2017'),
      array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2016'));

  for($l=0; $l< count($formatos); $l++){
 ?>
  <button onclick="enviar(<?php echo json_encode($formatos[$l]['idPeriodo'])?>)">Guardar</button>
<?php
      }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wrap the string in quotes, `var per= "<?php echo json_encode($formatos[$l]['idPeriodo']); ?>";`

Comment: Show us $formatos array

Comment: $formatos[$i]=  array('id'=>$empleadoPeriodo1->id,                     'nombre'=>$empleadoPeriodo1->user,   'idPeriodo'=>$empleadoPeriodo1->idperiodoacademico,      'periodo'=>$empleadoPeriodo1->descripcionperiodoacademico
                    );
                
                $i++;
                 }

Answer (score 0):

You get the last element of the array because you redefine `per` variable every time. Use this code:

```
<?php
$formatos=
    array(array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2019'),
          array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2018'),
          array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2017'),
          array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2016'));
for($l=0; $l< count($formatos); $l++){
    $param = json_encode($formatos[$l]['idPeriodo']);
    $param = addslashes($param);
    ?>
          <button onclick="enviar(<?php echo $param; ?>)">Guardar</button>
          <?php
          }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this code but it doesnt  work the  onclick event

Comment: @carlanoriega Show us the HTML you got using my modification (edit the question).

Comment: i modified my code, I put a new array instead the original,   
<?php     
     $formatos=   array(array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2019'),    array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2018'), array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2017'),  array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2016'));
        for($l=0; $l< count($formatos); $l++){  ?>
       <script>
      var periodo=<?php echo json_encode($formatos[$l]['idPeriodo'])?>;        
</script>
<button onclick="enviar(periodo)">Guardar</button>      
 
<?php
       
     }   
?>

Comment: @carlanoriega No, I need the HTML code that was generated.

Comment: @carlanoriega Ops, forgot to escate the quotes. Try again plz.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a PHP loop, so the javascript bit is useless.
Try this:

```
<?php     
for($l=0; $l< count($formatos); $l++){
    $per = json_encode($formatos[$l]['idPeriodo']);
?>
<button onclick="enviar('<?= $per ?>')">Guardar</button>
<?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you want it json_encode? this works. Try this :

**EDIT**

```
 <?php
   $formatos=    
   array(array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2019'),
   array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2018'),
   array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2017'), 
   array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2016'));


    for($l=0; $l< count($formatos); $l++){   


    $periodo = $formatos[$l]['idPeriodo'];        
   ?>
     <button onclick="enviar('<?php echo $periodo; ?>')">Guardar</button>      
   <?php
      }   
   ?>
```

Comment: @carla noriega  can you just print $formatos result array? ie `echo "<pre>"; print_r($formatos);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this script and hope this will work :

```
<?php
$formatos = array(
    array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2019'),
    array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2018'),
    array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2017'),
    array('idPeriodo'=>'pp2016')
);

for($l = 0; $l < count($formatos); $l++) {
?>
<button onclick='enviar(<?php echo json_encode($formatos[$l]['idPeriodo']);?>)'>Guardar</button>
<?php } ?>
```